# Intent constructor syntax

Tags: android

I am just starting to develop Android (being a .Net developer)

I am following the code from a book, and to start a new 'form' (screen) they show this code

```
Intent i = new Intent("net.learn2develop.ACTIVITY2");
```

The class definition is this:

```
package net.learn2develop.Activities;

//imports removed

public class Activity2 extends Activity {
```

My question is: i presume that the string in the constructor in the Intent is the classname.
But why is it `'net.learn2develop'` and not `'net.learn2develop.Activities'` and why is the classname all caps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at documentation: [Intent(String action)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29).

So this is actually action name, not class name. They usually look very similar to unprepared eye. Take a look at `AndroidManifest.xml` and search for `net.learn2develop.ACTIVITY2` string. You should find somehting like:

```
   <activity android:name=".Activity2" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY2" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Ok, so the Action name (android.intent.action.ACTIVITY2) is set in the constructor, and the Activity name (.Activity2) is the classname?

Comment: Do i have to specify the packagename somewhere?

Comment: If you use Actions, then this is not required. The whole idea of `Intent` is late binding. In other words, you don't have to know what package will handle your request.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use the class name as caps. In fact use it exactly the way you have declared it .
As android uses java as language and java is a case sensitive language.

For example to start the new acivity:

```
Intent i=new Intnet("net.learn2develop.Activity2"); //assuming that your package name is net.learn2develop
startActivity(i);
```

or

```
Intent i=new Intnet(Activity1.this,Activity2.class) //assuming that your current class name is Actvity1 
startActivity(i);
```

Finally dont forget to declare the new Activity in manifest file.